# listview scrolldown to load more views

Tags: android, json, web-services, listview

I'm a noob to android and I've read plenty of xamples ,but no success so far,so basically I want that my listview utilising a baseadapter adds more rows when I scroll down,and the mechanism for adding more rows would be to query the dynamic url again,now on implementing the on scroll function the query is made ,but the adapter generates a new list n discards the old one ,here's the code

```
public class Second extends Activity {

static final String Li_nk = "LinkName:";
static final String Image_name = "ImageName:";
// ListView list;
public final static String AUTH = "authentication";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_image";
// JSONObject j2;
String wrd;
int counter = 01;

// ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mylist;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent i2 = getIntent();
    wrd = i2.getStringExtra("entrd");
    Log.v("keyis", wrd);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // call the function
            LoadData();
            // also call the same runnable
            handler.postDelayed(this, 40000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runable, 10);

}

public void LoadData() {

    JSONObject j2 = JSONfunctions
            .getJSONfromURL("/webservice_search.php?keyword=" + wrd
                    + "&format=json&pagenum=" + counter);
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    try {
        JSONArray jray = j2.getJSONArray("listings");
        for (int i = 0; i < jray.length(); i++) {
            Log.v("state", "json data being read");
            JSONObject j3 = jray.getJSONObject(i);
            String first = j3.getString("listing");
            Log.v("sublist", first);
            JSONObject j4 = j3.getJSONObject("listing");
            String sec = j4.getString("links");

            int maxLength = (sec.length() < 30) ? sec.length() : 27;
            sec.substring(0, maxLength);
            String cutsec = sec.substring(0, maxLength);
            Log.v("links are", cutsec);
            String img = j4.getString("image_name");
            Log.v("image name is ", img);
            // Uri
            // dimg=Uri.parse("http://zeesms.info/android_app_images/Koala.jpg");
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("Id", String.valueOf(i));
            map.put(Li_nk, cutsec);
            map.put(Image_name, j4.getString("image_name"));

            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, "http://zeesms.info/android_app_images/"
                    + img);

            mylist.add(map);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        Log.e("loG_tag", "Error parsing" + e.toString());
    }
    final LazyAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, mylist);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
            R.layout.footer, null, false);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);
    list.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
    list.addFooterView(footerView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setItemsCanFocus(false);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Click ListItem Number "
            // + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                    .parse("http://www.google.com/"));
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });
    list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // what is the bottom iten that is visible

            int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if (lastInScreen == totalItemCount) {

                counter++;

                LoadData();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

    });
}
```

and the code for my adapter class is

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
//int count=5;


public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    Collections.reverse(d);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    /*position=1;
    position=2;
    position=3;
    position=4;
    position=5;*/
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view1, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.linkname); // merchnts name
    TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imagename); // address
    //TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id); // distance
   ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.mClogo); // logo

    HashMap<String, String> jsn = new HashMap<String, String>();
    jsn = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
   title.setText(jsn.get(Second.Li_nk));
   artist.setText(jsn.get(Second.Image_name));
    //duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(jsn.get(Second.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
```

now what would be the simplest way that either the new list appends the old one ,or is there any other way that it would add more views after scrolling ??

Answer (score 1):

you can add onscrollchange listener for the list view and when the last position is visible add the elements to it and also accordingly increase the size of the list view.

add one method in the lazyadapter say

```
setData(HashMap<string,string> newdata){
this.data = newdata;
}
```

everytime you hit the webservice and get the response append data to newConcretehashmap and call above method. by this you will be getting only newData updated in the hashmap. then just call notifydatasetchanged(); and the list will get updated.